# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in reactjs application

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the error : Cannot read property 'map' of undefined but when I doing a console log of items(which is the array used for mapping) comes out to be fine which means it has been correctly  passed through props but inside render it is not able to read the items array to map it

[image: image of result of console log]

```js
import React from 'react';

const ListGroup = (props) => {
  const { items, onItemSelect, currentGenre } = props;

  console.log(items);
  return (
    <ul className="list-group">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li
          onClick={() => onItemSelect(item)}
          key={item.id}
          className={item === currentGenre ? 'list-group-item active' : 'list-group-item'}
        >
          {item.name}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default ListGroup;
```

Can somebody please help me with this

Comment: Where is `items` defined? What is its initial value? Are you fetching items asynchronously?

Comment: Can you provide the result of your console.log?

Comment: where this items coming from and what is the initial state of that items?

Comment: change that from `{items.map(item=>(` to `{items.length > 0 && items.map(item=>(`

Comment: @NishargShah if `items` is undefined, `item.length` will lead to a similar error ---> `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: ohh, I didn't see that ;) change that from `{items.map(item=>(` to `{items && items.map(item=>(`

Comment: @NishargShah This worked thankyou  Can you why it was necessary to   include {items && }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to be sure that you are passing correct values as props of this component. In your case items is undefined at thus the result is an error. In order to be resilient to this types of errors you can have a condition like this:

```js
return (
  <ul className="list-group">
    {items && items.length
      ? items.map((item) => (
          <li
            onClick={() => onItemSelect(item)}
            key={item.id}
            className={item === currentGenre ? 'list-group-item active' : 'list-group-item'}
          >
            {item.name}
          </li>
        ))
      : null}
  </ul>
);
```

Instead of **null** you return any component as you see fit.

Comment: you can not add an answer after OP solved that with another user's answer, even if that is a comment

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not see you answered it in a comment. In future I will read comments frist